# How to post Content with REST api by anonymous user

Tags: 8

I have a content type that anonymous user can submit content, Now in a mobile application I want to let them submit content with REST API,

My snippet to submit :

```
(function($){

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: '/rest/session/token',
                        method: 'GET',
                        success: function (token, status, xhr) {
                            var postData = {}
                            postData.title = [{'value': 'My Basic Page'}];
                            postData.field_enroll_email = [{'value': 'yusef@gmail.com'}];
                            postData.type = 'enroll';
                            jQuery.ajax({
                                url: "/entity/node",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                                headers: {"Accept": "application/json", "X-CSRF-Token": token, "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                                success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                                    console.log(data);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
})(jQuery);
```

this work correctly in browser console when I'm logged in, and When I try it without login return "403 permission is denied". I set permission for anonymous user to create "mycontent1" content.
**I want to know how can   anonymous user post content with REST in Drupal? **

Comment: @NoSssweat it  has not acceptable answer yet and question is about how to get

Comment: An answer isn't right/wrong/acceptable because it has a tick next to it - and the HTTP method is irrelevant to the authentication layer, so nothing changes between `GET`/`POST`. The answer in the duplicate is the answer to this one too. If you need a more detailed answer, you can always open a bounty on it

Comment: @Clive because I am not sure about that first ask is it possible, now I change it to how . thanks for your note , it help me.

Comment: The answer to the new question is the same as the old one, it's in the answer to the duplicate. You need to _create your own authentication provider_, as the answer puts it, which directly answers "how". There's even a link to a tutorial. By all means post a more specific question with the code attempts if you can't get that provider working